# RadGrid Footer Issue --> display above the Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, radgrid

I am using a `RadGrid` with Show `Footer = true` and when I open this page in browser it is working fine. But when I send this grid by an email and open in Outlook my grid total will become shown above the items.
Please see below screen shot related to my issue in the Outlook

[image: Outlook Snapshot]

It looks fine in the browser (Firefox). But when I check the rendered HTML, the footer HTML is between the Header and Body.

My sample code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound"
DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" OnDeleteCommand="radGrid1_OnDeleteCommand" OnItemCommand="RadGridTask_ItemCommand"
ShowFooter="true" AllowSorting="false">
<MasterTableView OverrideDataSourceControlSorting="true" CommandItemDisplay="None"
    NoDetailRecordsText="" NoMasterRecordsText="" EnableNoRecordsTemplate="false"
    ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="false" EditMode="PopUp" DataKeyNames="LabourID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" />
    <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" Visible="True">
    </RowIndicatorColumn>
    <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" Visible="True">
    </ExpandCollapseColumn>
    <Columns>



        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalMins" HeaderText="Duration" SortExpression="TotalMins"
            UniqueName="TotalMins" HeaderStyle-Width="90px" FilterControlAltText="Filter TotalMins column"
            Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" ">
            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#872B07" CssClass="tb_head" />
            <ItemStyle Wrap="false" Width="90px" CssClass="tb_cell" />
            <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12px"></FooterStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalCharge" HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="TotalCharge"
            UniqueName="TotalCharge" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" FilterControlAltText="Filter TotalCharge column"
            Aggregate="Sum" FooterText="Total: ">
            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#872B07" CssClass="tb_head" />
            <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12px"></FooterStyle>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="false" Width="90px" CssClass="tb_cell" />
            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
</MasterTableView>
<ClientSettings>
</ClientSettings>
<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
</FilterMenu>
```

Comment: I don´t think the RadGrid is made to send it via E-Mail!!

You should export the Grid as Excel or PDF and sent it as E-Mail Attachment! http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/exporting/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: maybe helps preventing the Outlook from formatting http://www.msoutlook.info/question/624

Comment: Can you please provide your css class, so i will try to resolved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Have a try of this nifty little option:

The code-snippet below shows how to use the Gmail's SMTP server to send e-mail:

```
public void SendMail(string smtpAddress, string from, string to, string body, string subject, bool isHtml, Stream attachmentStream, string fileName)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress);
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
    email.From = new MailAddress(from);
    email.To.Add(to);    
    email.Body = body;
    email.Subject = subject;
    email.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentStream, fileName));

    NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential("youremail@gmail.com", "yourpassword", "");
    smtpClient.Credentials = myCreds;

    smtpClient.Send(email);
}
```

Notice how the export is 'cancelled' but the memorystream containing the exported 'file' is added as an attachment to the email. [Taken from here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/open-email-and-attach-grid-as-pdf-or-excel.aspx)

```
protected void RadGrid1_GridExporting(object source, GridExportingArgs e)
{
    if (e.ExportType == ExportType.Excel)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(e.ExportOutput));
        SendMail("smtp.gmail.com", "sourcemail@gmail.com", "targetmail@gmail.com", "mail body", "mail subject", false, ms, "ExportedFile.xls");
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Or if you just want to get the html and send it in the email then try this: [Taken from here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-to-attach-radgrid-data-to-mail.aspx)

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" Skin="Black" runat="server" GridLines="None" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource1">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
        <RowIndicatorColumn>
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
        </RowIndicatorColumn>
        <ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Send email - grid" />


protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource1(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    List<MailMessage> mList = new List<MailMessage>();
    MailMessage m1 = new MailMessage();
    m1.Subject = "One";
    mList.Add(m1);
    MailMessage m2 = new MailMessage();
    m2.Subject = "Two";
    mList.Add(m2);
    MailMessage m3 = new MailMessage();
    m3.Subject = "Three";
    mList.Add(m3);
    RadGrid1.DataSource = mList;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string GridRawHtml;
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter clearWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    RadGrid1.RegisterWithScriptManager = false;
    RadGrid1.RenderControl(clearWriter);
    GridRawHtml = clearWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
    GridRawHtml = GridRawHtml.Remove(GridRawHtml.IndexOf("<script"), GridRawHtml.LastIndexOf("</script>") - GridRawHtml.IndexOf("<script"));
    Response.Write(GridRawHtml);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because Telerik's controls use A LOT of JavaScript combined with Embedded resources (= A LOT of CSS). As @sine said in the comments of your question, these controls are clearly not designed for e-mail delivrability / portability. 
There is probably some JS that manages the footer position for the grid, JS that wouldn't be included in the Outlook mail (you should ask a question on Telerik's forum to be sure about that).

You should consider another way to generate your grid in a more "e-mail" friendly format, since this kind of HTML usually comes with delivrability / spam check issues aswell.